# Three.js video envmap

Tags: three.js

Im working on creating a cube that reflects of an video-envmap but I cant seam to find any solution or examples on how to do this just googeling.

I have a working example of the cube with an envmap consisting of jpgs [here](http://jonaaust.com/threejstest/testtwo.html)

I have tried to simply replace the jpgs with webm & mov video files, but it does not seam to work.

Can this even be done?

Here is a relevant snippet of my code:

```js
var env_url = [
  'textures/dawnmountain-xneg.png',
  'textures/dawnmountain-xneg.png',
  'textures/dawnmountain-xneg.png',
  'textures/dawnmountain-xneg.png',
  'textures/dawnmountain-xneg.png',
  'textures/dawnmountain-xneg.png'
];

var enviro = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(env_url);    

var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  envMap: enviro,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
  metal: true,
  combine: THREE.MixOperation, 
  reflectivity: 0.70,
  specular: 0x7a7a7a,
  bumpMap: mapHeight,
  bumpScale: 0.03,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done but not so automatically, and not without modifying three.js rendering code I think.

You need to update the three.js texture from the video. Video files don't work directly as textures on 3D objects, you can only use images directly like that.

For a normal texture, it is quite simple though and jetienne provides a nice simple utility for it at https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.videotexture -- there are demos too.

That is not supported out of the box for envMaps though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Antont!  Like you said it was super easy to map it to the rectangle itself using: map: texture. I've been tickling with jetienne's lib for a couple of hours now trying to find a way to get it onto the envMap but cant get it to work... To me it seams that envMap only allows for url's and not THREE.Textures?

Comment: i'd check the sources of envMap and, if needed, modify it accordingly to allow using a texture you give (internally in the end a texture is used anyhow). you can make your own copy of envmap for this.